# Where a person has advantage in a specific scenario

Tags: single-word-requests, popular-refrains, phrase-requests

> Sally and Tom live in the same street and are both looking for love. Both Sally and Tom have average looking faces.
>    Sally is a 37 year old overweight unemployed divorced stay-at-home mother of a 12 year old boy. Tom  is a fit single, childless, 32 year old with a stable job as a civil planner, enjoys the outdoors and is a runner. 
>   Sally and Tom join Tinder at the same time. Both add a single photo of themselves and list their hobbies and family circumstances.  Both Sally and Tom decide to swipe right(like) every photo they see on their screens.
>
> After both have done this for a thousand photos they only return to the app a week later. Sally has 200 mutual likes and message from men of various ages wanting to hook up. Tom has no mutual likes.

As a result Sally has a high expectation of her desirability and Tom forms a very low expectation of his desirability.

One could argue  people are *biased for* Sally/ *biased against*  Tom but in a real life scenario if Sally and Tom went independently to a club, Tom would get more  interest shown in him than Sally. So the word(s) I'm looking for is related to a specific scenario/use case i.e. Tinder but not in general.

If I look at words like *bias, prejudice, discrimination ,inequity, favouritism* it has the feeling of `unfair` which is not want I want to convey, but I rather want to say an illogical advantage not applicable to real life, just Tinder.

Since online dating sites like Tinder did not exist 20+ years ago the word I though of is

*Zeitgeist*

> Definition: noun
>   the defining spirit or mood of a particular period of history as shown by the ideas and beliefs of the time.

However what I am thinking of isn't related to a specific period but rather a situation e.g. realm of Tinder.

Other similar words *in vogue, feeling, atmosphere* just don't fit in what I am trying to say

How do I explain this either with  word(s) e.g. *zeitgeist* or alternatively with something to describe the *postive/negative bias* on each person?

Comment: Definitely not "zeitgeist" -- as you said, that's the spirit of the times, not the quirks of the platform. The best I can think of is something like women have a "platform-specific advantage" on dating apps like Tinder.

Comment: Don't limit yourself to a single word.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*[Social inequality](http://study.com/academy/lesson/what-is-social-inequality-in-sociology-definition-effects-causes.html)*

> Social inequality is the existence of unequal opportunities and rewards for different social positions or statuses within a group or society
>
> — Kimberly Moffitt on [study.com](http://study.com/academy/lesson/what-is-social-inequality-in-sociology-definition-effects-causes.html)

Comment: If this quote came from somewhere, please attribute it correctly.

Comment: OK. I'll do it myself. Perhaps I should have linked [the help page](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant linking